# Save animation of SCNScene as gif to photos library

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I have a SCNScene that is spinning 360 degrees at Y-axis. I want to save this animation as a gif to photos library.

I have tried taking screenshots and converting them in gif following [this](https://img.ly/blog/how-to-make-an-animated-gif-using-swift/#collectingframeimages) method.

This is how I'm taking the screenshots

```
 let totalFrames = 20
 var images: [CGImage] = []
 for i in 0..<totalFrames {
    print("creating image \(i)")
    images.append(sceneView.snapshot().cgImage!)
 }
```

20 frames is probably a very small number for `totalFrames`. However, increase in the number results in app crash due to memory usage.

Please let me know if this is the best way to go or if there is any other strategy that could be applied.

Answer (score 0):

The above mentioned method actually worked well. I had the code for animation and saving gif in one function which was a callback function for button. Having animation separately and saving gif on button press worked.